# node.js function should only return after mongodb query finished

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to get a value returned from a function which executes a mongodb query.
My problem is that the function returns nothing because the query isn't finished before it returns.

If I try console.log(checkChickenValue(2)); for example I get undefined back. Here is the relevant function:

```
function checkChickenValue(chickenid) {
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {

        var cursor = db.collection('games').find({}, {
            limit : 1,
            fields : {
                _id : 1
            },
            sort : {
                _id : -1
            }
        }).toArray(function(err, docs) {
            var id = docs[0]._id;
            var test = db.collection('games').findOne({
                _id : id
            }, function(err, result) {
                switch(chickenid) {
                case 1:
                    complete(result.chicken1.value);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    complete(result.chicken2.value);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    complete(result.chicken3.value);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    complete(result.chicken4.value);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    complete(result.chicken5.value);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    complete(result.chicken6.value);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    complete(result.chicken7.value);
                    break;
                case 8:
                    complete(result.chicken8.value);
                    break;
                }

            });

        });
    });
    function complete (value)
    {
        return value;
    }
};
```

How can I let the function wait until complete() is called?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: What is the `complete` function for?

Comment: Short answer: you can't.  See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to return your result via a callback. Add a 'callback' parameter to your function, representing a function that will be called when the result is ready.

```
function checkChickenValue(chickenid, callback)
{
```

Then when you have the result, return it via your callback:

```
switch(chickenid) {
    case 1:
        callback(complete(result.chicken1.value));
```

Then, to use your function, do something like this:

```
checkChickenValue(2, function(result){ console.log(result); });
```